# Triangular matrix matrix multiply `trmm` in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, blas

I need to get fastest possible matmul operation in TF for the case when one of the matrices is lower triangular. The cuBLAS and the BLAS have `trmm` functions, but looks like TensorFlow doesn't benefit from it.

I checked LinearOperators implementation for LowerTriangular case. But, it is not clear either it utilizes BLAS implementation or not.

Can anyone confirm that most optimized version is implemented by LinearOperators?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that function is used. From a quick look at the source, there are wrappers for using it from a TensorFlow kernel, but at least the GitHub search did not bring up any kernel actually using it.

Comment: You would have to go all the trouble to [add a new op](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op), and understand how the TensorFlow [stream executor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.h) and BLAS interface are used, e.g. looking at [`matmul_op.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.h) / [`matmul_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc).